# Pandas dataframe: group by some columns and create lists from the remaining ones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My sample dataframe contains:

| id1 | id2 | text | metadata |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HP:001 | DO:001 | text_1 | metadata_1 |
| HP:001 | DO:001 | text_2 | metadata_2 |

I am trying to generate a new table, grouped by `id1` and `id2`, where `text` and `metadata` will contain a list of terms from their respective records:

| id1 | id2 | text | metadata |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HP:001 | DO:001 | ['text_1', 'text_2'] | ['metadata_1', 'metadata_2'] |

I tried to use groupby with apply and reset_index, but I get:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"id1": ["HP:001", "HP:001"], 
                   "id2": ["DO:001", "DO:001"], 
                   "text": ["text_1", "text_2"], 
                   "metadata": ["metadata_1", "metadata_2"]})

outcome = df.groupby(["id1", "id2"]).apply(list)
```

The outcome is:

```
id1     id2   
HP:001  DO:001    [id1, id2, text, metadata]
dtype: object
```

I can parse the outcome into a dataFrame with `reset_index`, but I don't understand why I get a list of column names rather than their content as the outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change apply to `agg`

```
outcome = df.groupby(["id1", "id2"]).agg(list)#.reset_index()

outcome
Out[372]: 
                           text                  metadata
id1    id2                                               
HP:001 DO:001  [text_1, text_2]  [metadata_1, metadata_2]
```

Answer (score 1):

With `df.groupby(["id1", "id2"]).apply(list)`, you can view it as `df.groupby(["id1", "id2"]).apply(lambda group: list(group))` where `group` is a DataFrame. `list(DataFrame)` returns the column names.

Comment: Thanks, that's clarifying!